# How to return model object as json after post request in DRF?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my django rest api I have a view which adds a debt by creating a new Debt model instance and saving it. If this operation is successful, the api should return a response containing the newly created Debt model instance as json. The function in the model responsible for adding a debt and returning it is this:

```
def add_debt(self, from_user, to_user,
            paying_user, receiving_user,
            amount, currency, description, 
            date_incurred, deadline, payed, overdue):
    """ Create a debt request """
    if from_user == to_user:
        raise ValidationError("Users cannot be in debt with themselves")

    request, created = DebtRequest.objects.get_or_create(
        from_user=from_user,
        to_user=to_user,
        paying_user=paying_user,
        receiving_user=receiving_user,
        amount=amount,
        currency=currency,
        description=description,
        date_incurred=date_incurred,
        deadline=deadline,
        payed=payed,
        overdue=overdue)

    debt_request_created.send(sender=request)
    return request
```

In my view I have the following:

```
class DebtRequestCreate(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        other_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data["friend_pk"])
        amount = request.data["amount"]
        currency = request.data["currency"]
        description = request.data["description"]
        date_incurred = request.data["date_incurred"]
        deadline = request.data["deadline"]
        is_payed = request.data["is_payed"]
        is_overdue = request.data["is_overdue"]

        is_in_debt = request.data["is_in_debt"]

        debt = None
        if is_in_debt: # is the request.user in debt
            debt = Debt.objects.add_debt(
                request.user, # From user
                other_user, # To user
                request.user, # Paying user                     
                other_user, # Receiving user
                amount, currency, description, date_incurred,
                deadline, is_payed, is_overdue)
        else:
            debt = Debt.objects.add_debt(
                request.user, # From user
                other_user, # To user
                other_user, # Paying user                     
                request.user, # Receiving user
                amount, currency, description, date_incurred,
                deadline, is_payed, is_overdue)

        return Response(status=201)
```

Instead of returning the status code I want to return a json version of the `debt` object. I have the following function which I use to convert a list of `Debt` objects to json in another view:

Other view important code:

```
debt_requests_list = Debt.objects.requests(user=request.user)
debt_requests_list_json = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', debt_requests_list))

debt_requests_json = [debt_requests_json_format(x, request.user.id) 
    for x in debt_requests_list_json]

return JsonResponse(debt_requests_json, safe=False)
```

The function:

```
def debt_requests_json_format(x, user_pk):
    fields = x["fields"]
    # if == True --> Debt request addressed to current user.
    if fields["to_user"] == user_pk:
        return {"pk": x["pk"],
        "created": fields["created"],
        "is_user_to_user": True,
        "current_user_pk": user_pk,
        "from_user": fields["from_user"],
        "from_user_first_name": User.objects.get(pk=fields["from_user"]).firstName,
        "from_user_last_name": User.objects.get(pk=fields["from_user"]).lastName,
        "paying_user": fields["paying_user"],
        "receiving_user": fields["receiving_user"],
        "amount": fields["amount"],
        "currency": fields["currency"],
        "payed": fields["payed"],
        "description": fields["description"],
        "date_incurred": fields["date_incurred"],
        "deadline": fields["deadline"],
        "overdue": fields["overdue"]}
    else: # if == False --> Debt request has been sent by current user.
        return {"pk": x["pk"],
        "created": fields["created"],
        "is_user_to_user": False,
        "current_user_pk": user_pk,
        "to_user": fields["to_user"],
        "to_user_first_name": User.objects.get(pk=fields["to_user"]).firstName,
        "to_user_last_name": User.objects.get(pk=fields["to_user"]).lastName,
        "paying_user": fields["paying_user"],
        "receiving_user": fields["receiving_user"],
        "amount": fields["amount"],
        "currency": fields["currency"],
        "payed": fields["payed"],
        "description": fields["description"],
        "date_incurred": fields["date_incurred"],
        "deadline": fields["deadline"],
        "overdue": fields["overdue"]}
```

Can I use this function to convert the single debt object to json and return it to my client using JsonResponse?

Comment: Why you don use serializers and createmodelmixin http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin ?

Comment: I want to add extra fields that aren't in the model so I do it myself.

Comment: But how would I use the create model mixin